# Is there a way to use spring integration tcp udp adapter with tibco rv?

Tags: spring-integration, tibco-rv

I have a legacy app which uses Tibco RV to publish and subscribe. I am rewriting the app to spring boot app. Now, I am trying to remove Tibco RV dependency. Is there a way to use spring integration UDP adapter to publish and subscribe to/from Tibco RV subjects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a way to reinvent a Tibco RV Java Client... What is the point to getting rid of Tibco RV dependency? They provided and support that API and it should be fully enough to use in Spring Integration's Service Activator as a POJO method invocation.

Comment: I have lot of apps using TibcoRV and I intend to port them away from RV one by one. I will look at the service activator.

Comment: Wait. Is your question that your would like to move your apps away from the TibcoRV at all and are intended to use some other messaging middleware, e.g. Apache Kafka?

Comment: Yes, that is my ideal state to be . to move away from tibcoRv and use Kafka. that is the next phase. for now, i was looking at ways to deploy my app in PCF without TibcoRv . To achieve, this i was exploring spring integration or how to use tibcoRv remote daemon.  Tibco Rv is new to me and from the docs , i thought it uses UDP and since spring integration has an  UDP adapter , it seemed like a possible solution to me.  my first preference is to use spring integration and second is to use tibco rv remote daemon. I would appreciate if you can provide any insight on both solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard UDP adapter to receive TibRV messages, but they will be presented to you just as byte buffers. You won't have an API to see the individual fields. How exactly Tibco chose to pack fields into the UDP buffer is part of a proprietary (unpublished) protocol.

So your best bet is probably to use the Tibrv Java API from your Spring project and port your publishers/subscribers one to one to Kafka. Another, smoother, transition might be to port all your Apps to JMS and then use a JMS Wrapper around TibRv and later Apache Kafka.